# will elementary run on a Centrino 2 duo core @ 2000 Mhz?

Tags: system-installation

My question is will elementary run on a Centrino 2 duo core @ 2000 Mhz?

Comment: You can always try elementary OS in a Live session to check hardware compatibility. Then you can check your internet connection, sound, graphics... Have in mind that a Live session is much slower than installation but it will give you an idea of your hardware compatibility with elementary that can prevent problems later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to. I recently replaced chromOS on the Acer chromebook 14 and it hasn't had any problems running simple tasks. This machine has the Celeron N3160 which runs at 1.6GHz. I have not done anything very system intensive to see if there are any problems but the OS animations all run smooth and the CPU doesn't seem to be struggling and heating up. Hope this helps.